# Find TFS server file path from locally mapped workspace file path

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

I am working on a tool that can compare two files using a custom Diff functionality.
I wish to add functionality to compare a file in the locally-mapped workspace to its server version (similar to Visual studio functionality "Compare with server version").
In this case, I will get the local file path as input, and I need to determine its equivalent server path on the TFS.

E.g. ***Local Path*** is : D:\xyz\abc\t1588.cs

I need the server path that will look something like

***Server path***: $/HelloWorldProject/abc/t1588.cs

Are there any APIs provided by TFS that can be used for this?
Any help/links are appreciated.

Comment: What research have you done on the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any APIs provided by TFS that can be used for this?

From your description, I guess that you means the following similar feature.

[image]

As far as I know, I am afraid that there is no such API that can directly meet your needs.

I recommend that you could use the TF command for this requirement.

You could try the [TF workfolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/workfold-command?view=azure-devops) command.

For example:

`tf workfold localfolder [/login:username,[password]]`

[image]

The result could return the server path and local path.

Comment: Thank you. This works for my needs. Much appreciated.